# Im getting the error "{"error":{"code":null,"message":"The URI is malformed."}}", when "&" is passed in the api below

Tags: python, api, python-behave, coda

```
def get_dw_dim_channel_by_channel(self, channel):
    url = 'db-warehouse-dw/dim_channel?$filter=channel_name eq \'{}\''.format(channel)
    print ("debug: url = {}{}".format(self.host, url))
    return self.get(url, headers=self.headers, auth=self.auth)
```

Here the value for channel_name is "WDC Kitchen & Bath Center".

The error after executing the above code:

```json
{"error":{"code":null,"message":"The URI is malformed."}}
```

What must I do to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

The ampersand needs to be percent-encoded.
Try to use:

```
channel = channel.replace("&", "%26")
```